# How do you upload your module to Python testing site at https://testpypi.python.org/pypi on a Windows 7 computer?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

My tools:
Windows 7 , 
Python 3.4.2

I am going through Chapter 2 of Head First Python by Paul Barry Nov 2010 .

Part of the requirements is to upload my distribution to PyPI testing site.

Unfortunately I haven't been successful.

All the reading I have done so far say that I need to make use of this HOME environment variable in Windows, or put .pypirc in the home directory of Windows 7.

Well, there is no such environment variable in Windows 7, nor such directory.

..........Can somebody please give me a step by step guide using the command line tool in Windows 7?

So far, I have created a    .pypirc.txt     file in this directory      C:\Python34\nesterhead  , where my module is residing in Windows 7.

I then used the command line tool to rename the     .txt file   from    .pypirc.txt     to   .pypirc.   , i.e.

cd C:\Python34\nesterhead

REN  .pypirc.txt     .pypirc.

c:\python34\python.exe setup.py register -r pypitest

..........And I got this as the output.

ValueError: pypitest not found in .pypirc

..........I have done all the things I am supposed to do , including confirming my registration and checking "I agree' with https://testpypi.python.org/pypi

..........I have also followed the instructions from http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html  and have the following code with the correct usernames and passwords in my       .pypirc.txt

```
        [distutils] 
        index-servers =
          pypi
          pypitest

        [pypi]
        repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
        username: {{your_username}}
        password: {{your_password}}

        [pypitest]
        repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
        username: {{your_username}}
        password: {{your_password}}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo %userprofile%
```

This will display your home directory in windows 7